# vim replace pattern with carriage return

Tags: vim

Moved to a new company and cannot get my vim right again...

Suppose I want to replace every `:` character in a line with an actual carriage return (newline).

I can type `esc` to get a command line, then `.s/:/^V^M/g`. (That's CTRL-V then CTRL-M).
When typed, it appears on my screen as `.s/:/<C-M>/g`.

What I see goes from this:

```
PATH=/u/home/me/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/another/path/bin
```

to this:

```
PATH=/u/home/me/bin<C-M>/usr/bin<C-M>/bin<C-M>/another/path/bin
```

The colons are just replaced with those five characters `<C-M>`.  Rats!
If I put `\n` or `\\n` then I just get those characters instead.

The only way I can make it work is to pipe the line through `sed` and do the replacement there: `.!sed -e 's/:/\n/g`.  This is my desired result...

```
PATH=/u/home/me/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/another/path/bin
```

How can I fix this...?

edit:
This works:  `.s/:/\r/g`, but is different than "before".  What controls this.  It's not `magic/nomagic`.

edit2: FULL OUTPUT OF `vim --version` (which I did not build):

```
-bash$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Nov  1 2020 22:01:35)
Included patches: 1-1361
Compiled by root@us01linit1-vm
Huge version with GTK2 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               -farsi             +mouse_sgr         +tag_binary
+arabic            +file_in_path      -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_old_static
+autocmd           +find_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tag_any_white
+autochdir         +float             +mouse_xterm       -tcl
-autoservername    +folding           +multi_byte        +termguicolors
+balloon_eval      -footer            +multi_lang        +terminal
+balloon_eval_term +fork()            -mzscheme          +terminfo
+browse            +gettext           +netbeans_intg     +termresponse
++builtin_terms    -hangul_input      +num64             +textobjects
+byte_offset       +iconv             +packages          +textprop
+channel           +insert_expand     +path_extra        +timers
+cindent           +ipv6              +perl/dyn          +title
+clientserver      +job               +persistent_undo   +toolbar
+clipboard         +jumplist          +popupwin          +user_commands
+cmdline_compl     +keymap            +postscript        +vartabs
+cmdline_hist      +lambda            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_info      +langmap           +profile           +virtualedit
+comments          +libcall           +python/dyn        +visual
+conceal           +linebreak         +python3/dyn       +visualextra
+cryptv            +lispindent        +quickfix          +viminfo
+cscope            +listcmds          +reltime           +vreplace
+cursorbind        +localmap          +rightleft         +wildignore
+cursorshape       +lua               +ruby/dyn          +wildmenu
+dialog_con_gui    +menu              +scrollbind        +windows
+diff              +mksession         +signs             +writebackup
+digraphs          +modify_fname      +smartindent       +X11
+dnd               +mouse             -sound             -xfontset
-ebcdic            +mouseshape        +spell             +xim
+emacs_tags        +mouse_dec         +startuptime       +xpm
+eval              -mouse_gpm         +statusline        +xsmp_interact
+ex_extra          -mouse_jsbterm     -sun_workshop      +xterm_clipboard
+extra_search      +mouse_netterm     +syntax            -xterm_save
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/path/to/RHEL7/vim-8.2/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng15 -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libdrm     -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       
Linking: gcc   -L. -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE   -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim   -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lfreetype   -lSM -lICE -lXpm -lXt -lX11 -lSM -lICE  -lm -ltinfo -lelf  -lselinux   -lacl -lattr -ldl  -L/usr/lib -llua -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE  -fstack-protector  -L/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE -lperl -lresolv -lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lpthread -lc
```

Edit4:

Another solution that works for me is to use `.s/:/^v<enter>/g`.  Instead of `ctrl-v`, then `ctrl-m`, I can use `ctrl-v`, then just the `enter` key.  This makes the most sense to me, and is easier to remember than `\r`.

Comment: I'm not sure what "before" you refer to, but `:[range]s/:/\r/g` has been the canonical way to do what you ask since forever. See `:help s/\r`. As for typing `<C-v><C-m>` in the command-line, it is supposed to insert `^M`, not `<C-M>`. Can you reproduce the problem with `$ vim -Nu NONE`? Can we see the full output of `$ vim --version`?

Comment: I think you're mistaking "before" with `<C-V><CR>` which will show up in Vim as `^M` and insert a line break. This works like `\r` - it's only more cumbersome to type. See `:help c_CTRL-V`.

Comment: @romainl: Indeed the behavior is the same when I use `gvim -Nu NONE`, but when I use `vim -Nu NONE` (or even just `vim`, I get the behavior that I WANT and expect.  In `vim` when I type ^V^M, I get just the "^M" that I expect, not the replacement with "<C-M>".  Vim changes the color to let me know it's a special character.  My `.gvimrc` is mostly about colorscheme and guiOptions...

Comment: Your `gvimrc` is not sourced when you do `$ gvim -Nu NONE` so *your* config is not at fault, here. Only your GVim is acting weird so I would look into how it was built and how it is run instead. `--version` seems fine but the line `root@us01linit1-vm` makes me wonder if you are using it in a VM. In any case, you should open an issue regarding the expansion of `<C-m>` (the original goal of substituting colons with newlines is irrelevant). Also, note that Vim is now at version 9.1.

Comment: In other words, the way you are trying to solve the initial problem is fine. Using `\r` is generally better but using `<C-v>` to insert a literal `^M` is theoretically OK, too. The actual problem that you are facing is that the expansion is not made correctly in GVim while it is made correctly in Vim. This is issue tracker material.

Comment: Thanks @romainl.  I will use `/r` for now.
I'll build my own vim/gvim when I have some time and see if I can reproduce it in recent environments.  The Citrix/VM layer could also contribute.
Thank you for your help.